# errors building phpsh in terminal

Tags: php, python, macos

https://github.com/facebook/phpsh

I am following the instructions on the phpsh github page I navigate to the phpsh directory and run

```
python setup.py build
```

and I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 13, in p = Popen(["make", "-C", make_dir])
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in init
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1228, in _execute_child
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

it seems the files in my python directory actually end in pyo...

not sure what to do about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't have `make` installed. There are several places where you can get it, but the official way is to install the Xcode command-line tools, which (I believe), despite their name, do not actually require Xcode.